# How to show Toast in Desired date with AlarmManager on Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-broadcast

In my application I want show Toast in **Desired date**. For this I know I should use `AlarmManager`.
And for this `AlarmManager` I find source code from internet.
In this source give time from user with time picker but I want get time static.
I want show Toast in below date : 
**Date : 2017-10-26**
**Time : 06:49:59**

**MainActivity codes:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //the timepicker object
    TimePicker timePicker;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //getting the timepicker object
        timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        //attaching clicklistener on button
        findViewById(R.id.buttonAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //We need a calendar object to get the specified time in millis
                //as the alarm manager method takes time in millis to setup the alarm
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                            timePicker.getHour(), timePicker.getMinute(), 0);
                } else {
                    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                            timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
                }


                setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            }
        });
    }

    private void setAlarm(long time) {
        //getting the alarm manager
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //creating a new intent specifying the broadcast receiver
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyAlarm.class);

        //creating a pending intent using the intent
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);

        //setting the repeating alarm that will be fired every day
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Broadcast codes:**

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //the method will be fired when the alarm is triggerred
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //you can check the log that it is fired
        //Here we are actually not doing anything
        //but you can do any task here that you want to be done at a specific time everyday
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm just fired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

How can I it? I am amateur, please help me <3

Comment: you're showing toast two time !

Comment: @Fakher, ok. but how can I set time such as above? can you help me? please

Comment: When you call your method setAlarm(new Date()) pass as argument the date you want. And delete the code of picking a date

Comment: @Fakher, can you send to me code with my above codes? because I am amateur and I really need your help. please

Comment: I posted an answer

Comment: Sorry for the necropost, but to those following this example who can't see your broadcast, remember to register your broadcast receiver in manifest file.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Example (paste to NP++ and format it yourself):
<application
...
<activity
...
</activity>
<receiver android:name=".NotificationAlarmReceiver"  android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a date with your choice and pass it to your method setAlarm()

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    String dateInString = "26-10-2017 06:49:59";
    long alarmDate = 0L;
    try {
        Date d = sdf.parse(dateInString);
        alarmDate = d.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks my dear friend, but when use your code? can you edit your code and send to me full code with my above codes? please

Comment: Put this code inside onClick and delete the code already exists you don't need it

Comment: show me this error :`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.simplifiedlearning.alarmmanagerexample/net.simplifiedlearning.alarmmanagerexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: 26-10-2017 15:11:00`

Comment: It was an error in parsing the date. Try the new answer

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

```
 new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
         @Override
         public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {
                 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

                 setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
           }
 }, hr1, min1, false).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2017, 10, 26, 6, 49, 59);
        setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    }

    private void setAlarm(long time) {
        //getting the alarm manager
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //creating a new intent specifying the broadcast receiver
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyAlarm.class);

        //creating a pending intent using the intent
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);

        //setting the alarm that will be fired once
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, time, pi);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

See [GregorianCalendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Comment: thanks my dear friend, but when use your code? can you edit your code and send to me full code with my above codes? please

Comment: thanks my friend,in your codes for hourOfDay use 24h or 12h ? in here 6 is am or pm ? thanks

Comment: Yes, I did that. Hours are 24-based

Comment: note that this uses standard time zones, you might need to adjust if you are in a different timezone